# error with curl on post

Tags: php, curl

this is my index

```
<body>
<form id="form1"  method="post" name="entrar" action="procesar.php">
 <p>Usuario
<label for="username">:</label>
<input type="text" name="username" id="username">
</p>
<p>
<label for="pass">Clave:</label>
<input type="password" name="pass" id="pass">
</p>
<p>
<input type="submit" name="entrar" id="button" value="Enviar">
</p>
</form>
</body>
```

this is de code of procesa.php when check the values username and pass

```
<?php
if($_POST['entrar']){

$user = $_POST['username'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];

if($user == 'gato' && $pass == 'gato'){

    setcookie('control','1234',time()+30000,'/','www.onlinelatino.org');

    header("Location: sitio.php");
    }
else{
    header("Location: error.php");
    }       
}

else{

    echo "error inclucion no valida";
}
    ?>
```

later go to here

```
<!doctype html>
   <html>
        <head><title>Welcome</title></head>
<body>
<?php
   $control = $_COOKIE['control'];

   if($control == 1234){  
   ?>
<h1>Hola mundo</h1>
<h2>Como estas</h2>

<?php
   }
   else{       
       echo "No estas logado";
       }
   ?>

</body>
</html>
```

this work fine but i wanna access to site when a robots this is a code

```
 <?php
      $parametros_post = 'username='.urlencode("gato").'&pass='.urlencode("gato").'&entrar'.urlencode("Enviar");
         $cookie_file = "cookie.txt";
      $ch = curl_init(); 
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.onlinelatino.org/curl/procesar.php");
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01 Windows NT 5.0)");
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Accept-Language: es-es, en"));

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $parametros_post);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $error = curl_error($ch);
    curl_close($ch);    

    echo $result;

    echo $error;

?>
```

but no start the sesion with the cookie
only say say this "error inclucion no valida" this are on procesar.php
the link of the example is this 
http://www.onlinelatino.org/curl/index.html
and the robot is this
http://www.onlinelatino.org/curl/bot.php

I don't have idea when are the error

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking.

Comment: I need to enter the account from here  bot.php
http://www.onlinelatino.org/curl/bot.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
'&entrar'.urlencode("Enviar")
```

You're missing an =

```
'&entrar='.urlencode("Enviar")
```

Comment: thanks man is nice and the cookie is created  but now the page is blank 
you  know why happened this

Comment: Why it's blank? Hmmmm

Comment: I don't know 
must show this 
"Hola mundo
Como estas"
but the page is blank :/